# Why I can't get the elements with the same class content?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addData" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="">ADD New User</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <form method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="name" class="control-label">Name:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="location" class="control-label">Location:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="location" >
                  <div id="location-results"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="website" class="control-label">Website:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="website" >
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="create" name="create" >ADD</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then when I type something in the `input` with `id=location` some data will be inserted into the `div` with `id='location-results'` beneath the location input , I use Ajax to get the locations from locations table in the Database .

```
function findLocation(){
     //Get the Value From Location Search Input.
    var locationQuery = $('#location').val();
    //Send Ajax Request To findlocation.php File That Connects To The Locations Database And Return 5 `<p>` Elements With Location Name Inside Each `<p>`.
     $.ajax({ 
         url:"findlocation.php",
         type: 'POST',
         async: true,
         //Passing The Value From Location Search Input.
         data: {"locationQuery": locationQuery}, 
         success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
             //Insert Returned 5 `<p>` Elements Into The Div With ID location-results Beneath The Searching Input.
             $('#location-results').html( data  ); 
         }

    });
}
//Run findLocation (The Function Above) on Specific Events.
$( "#location" ).on('keyup input paste cut', findLocation);
```

The data back from the Ajax request looks like:

```
<p class="foundLocation" >First Place</p>
<p class="foundLocation" >Second Place</p>
<p class="foundLocation" >Third Place</p>
<p class="foundLocation" >Fourth Place</p>
<p class="foundLocation" >Fifth Place</p>
```

Then when I click one of the fetched location I should get the element content

```
//Select All Elements With Class foundLocation (The 5 p elements).
var found_locations = document.querySelectorAll('.foundLocation');
found_locations.forEach(function(el){
    //On Clicking On One Of The 5 `p` Elements.
    el.addEventListener('click', function(){
        //Insert Location Name Inside The Clicked `p` Element Into The Location Searching Input.
        $('#location').val(locationName);
    }); 
});
```

But when I click on one of the `p` elements with `class='foundLocation'` , Nothing happens , I even tried to `console.log('some text');` inside the `found_locations.forEach(function(el){` scope , But nothing is printed in the console.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Why `.querySelectorAll()` and `.addEventListener()` when there's already jQuery?

Comment: @Andreas Otherwise, why jQuery ? ;)

Comment: @Andreas , I tried `$('.foundLocation').each(function(){` too but nothing happened

Comment: @SergeK. , Because I'm using Bootstrap and other Jquery Plugins.

Answer (score 0):

When you update the DOM using AJAX you have to bind the event to the inserted elements.Try this code.

```
$(document).on("click",".foundLocation",function(){
     $(this).val(locationName);
});
```